# Trilogy Database Design

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

I hope this is a quick question, but could someone tell me if a single database was used to maintain all 4 sites (stackoverflow.com, serverfault.com, meta.stackoverflow.com, superuser.com) or if each site has their own database.

The same applies for the code-base, is it one managed code-base, or are changes maintained on one master copy, and then pushed out to the aforementioned sites.

Thanks,
Kyle

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would hope/imagine different databases that just happen to have identical (for the most part?) schemas.

You don't want one database failure to bring down four sites.

Comment: Why don't you visit Meta any more? :( You are an awesome user. Your answers are great.

Answer (score 3):

There's different databases per site.  Generally speaking, if you're not talking about rolling out thousands of sites, it's easier this way for scalability purposes.  Makes it easier to split the databases out onto different servers later if load requires.

Answer (score 1):

My imagination has it as one DB server, one redundant DB server that's getting mirrored updates from the master DB server, and 4 Databases in each server.

I further imagine that there's 1 source tree that contains the code for all the sites, but that there's some 4 production source trees that get updated from this 1 tree. They contain differences in the CSS, Web.config, and other details that differentiate the sites.

Potentially there's some configuration in each database, like required tags.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I don't think they currently have a redundant DB server for warm swap. I think they've got another server sitting in the data center configured and waiting to be installed if either the db server or one of the IIS servers goes donw.

Comment: I'd assumed that the least loaded web server (the one with Meta on it) might be handling that secondary DB backup, but I also wasn't sure how the backups were handled.